# Is it possible to get Google Fit API sensor data without Google Fit App installed?

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm trying to make an Android app to count the steps using the Google Fit API. What I was able to do was getting the steps from the sensors, but only with the Google Fit app installed. If the Google Fit app isn't installed on the device, my application doesn't receive any data from the sensors. Is that intentional (to get data from Google Fit API sensors I need the app installed) or is something I did wrong?

Comment: No. You don't need to have google fit app installed to get step count data from google fit sensor api. you might have taken something in wrong way.

Comment: Yes, I can know get it, but I don't know what I did wrong before to it not detect the steps.

Comment: How to did it. Need guidance. I am only getting step if GoogleFit app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to get Google Fit API sensors data.

You should use Google Fit Recording API to use Sensors API without installed Google Fit app.

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record

The general point is next - your application should subscribe for some data types to collect the data without installed Google Fit app. In the case when Google Fit app is installed you don't need to use recording API because Google Fit app already uses it.